# How can I cancel/delete unsent E-Mails from iOS Mail?

Tags: ios, email

If I'm off-line, and I send an e-mail, it stays as "unsent message".

Is there a way to cancel or delete or edit those unsent messages? (using the default e-mail app)

[image]

Comment: Swipe and delete? Works on mine.

Comment: works on mine also.

Comment: @iampearce where's this option?

Comment: Swipe left on the message and hit delete. :)

Comment: @iampearce there's no message, just a text on the bottom "1 Unsent Message". Please, see my screenshot update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back as far as you can in the Mail view. There should be an Outbox folder.

The unsent mail will be in there.

Then you can use the "Swipe to delete method" or tap "Edit" button and delete away.

Comment: Great! I think the text about the unsent message should be a link to that Outbox. Thanks!